# Cocos2D 3.2.1 Parallax Test Crashes on Mac OS X 10.10, XCode 6.1

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocos2d-iphone, xcode6

Running the cocos2d tests under my Mac. The Parallax Test hangs and crashes, running under Mac OSX 10.10, XCode 6.1.  A few other tests are crashing also.

> cocos2d-tests-osx-xcodeproj

Here's the dump:

```
2014-10-28 19:16:10.040 cocos2d-ui-tests-osx[92611:3249413] CCGLView loaded
cocos2d: Cocos2D-Swift version 3.2.1
cocos2d: Director's thread: Main thread
cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
cocos2d: OS version: Version 10.10 (Build 14A389) (0x000a0000)
cocos2d: 64 bit runtime
cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   ATI Technologies Inc.
cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: AMD Radeon HD 6630M OpenGL Engine
cocos2d: GL_VERSION:  2.1 ATI-1.28.29
cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 16384
cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS: 16
cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 8
cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: NO
cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: NO
cocos2d: GL supports shareable VAO: YES
2014-10-28 19:16:12.035 cocos2d-ui-tests-osx[92611:3249413] cocos2d: startAnimation
2014-10-28 19:16:20.630 cocos2d-ui-tests-osx[92611:3249413] NSXMLParser does not support reentrant parsing.
2014-10-28 19:16:20.632 cocos2d-ui-tests-osx[92611:3249413] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e46664c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8a5666de objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff8e4664fd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8f991d5d +[NSXMLParser setCurrentParser:] + 150
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8f992559 -[NSXMLParser parseFromStream] + 52
    5   cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x00000001000d499b -[CCTiledMapInfo parseXMLData:] + 203
    6   cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x00000001000d4d3f -[CCTiledMapInfo parseXMLFile:] + 303
    7   cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x00000001000d542f -[CCTiledMapInfo parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:] + 1695
    8   Foundation                          0x00007fff8f994d33 _startElementNs + 2857
    9   libxml2.2.dylib                     0x00007fff89e639bd xmlParseStartTag2 + 4357
    10  libxml2.2.dylib                     0x00007fff89e66734 xmlParseTryOrFinish + 3703
    11  libxml2.2.dylib                     0x00007fff89e656c8 xmlParseChunk + 901
    12  Foundation                          0x00007fff8f99222e -[NSXMLParser parseData:] + 275
    13  Foundation                          0x00007fff8f99249e -[NSXMLParser parseData:] + 899
    14  Foundation                          0x00007fff8f9925f9 -[NSXMLParser parseFromStream] + 212
    15  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x00000001000d499b -[CCTiledMapInfo parseXMLData:] + 203
    16  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x00000001000d4d3f -[CCTiledMapInfo parseXMLFile:] + 303
    17  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x00000001000d4827 -[CCTiledMapInfo initWithFile:] + 199
    18  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x00000001000d4227 +[CCTiledMapInfo formatWithTMXFile:] + 87
    19  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x00000001000d2122 -[CCTiledMap initWithFile:] + 402
    20  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x00000001000d1547 +[CCTiledMap tiledMapWithFile:] + 87
    21  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x000000010001f1ae -[ParallaxTest setupParallaxTest1] + 334
    22  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x000000010003de1e -[TestBase setupTestWithIndex:] + 270
    23  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x000000010003d0f2 -[TestBase init] + 5762
    24  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x000000010003d2d4 +[TestBase sceneWithTestName:] + 116
    25  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x000000010003b324 -[MainMenu selectedRow:] + 228
    26  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x0000000100185f92 __34-[CCTableView setTarget:selector:]_block_invoke + 82
    27  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x0000000100186102 -[CCTableView triggerAction] + 114
    28  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x0000000100186081 -[CCTableView selectedRow:] + 81
    29  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x00000001001840bc -[CCTableViewCell pressedCell:] + 156
    30  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x0000000100157cb2 __32-[CCControl setTarget:selector:]_block_invoke + 82
    31  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x0000000100157dc2 -[CCControl triggerAction] + 114
    32  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x0000000100155ce5 -[CCButton triggerAction] + 149
    33  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x0000000100155b85 -[CCButton mouseUpInside:] + 85
    34  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x0000000100157fd3 -[CCControl mouseUp:] + 83
    35  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x000000010014fc0c -[CCResponderManager mouseUp:button:] + 300
    36  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x000000010014ffe9 -[CCResponderManager mouseUp:] + 105
    37  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x00000001000e2ada -[CCGLView mouseUp:] + 122
    38  AppKit                              0x00007fff83e080cb -[NSWindow _reallySendEvent:] + 759
    39  AppKit                              0x00007fff8389565c -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 368
    40  AppKit                              0x00007fff838471e6 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 2238
    41  AppKit                              0x00007fff836d3fe8 -[NSApplication run] + 711
    42  AppKit                              0x00007fff836bf424 NSApplicationMain + 1832
    43  cocos2d-ui-tests-osx                0x000000010003a60b main + 59
    44  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff88e265c9 start + 1
    45  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

This is a [bug introduced by iOS8](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-swift/issues/964) that has been tracked and is now fixed. Maybe 'pull' the latest cocos2d would solve your issue.

edit : missed the obvious, that bug was iOS, but it had the same error (parse reentrancy error). Maybe submit new bug report on github, this time for osx.

Comment: Downloaded newer version but now getting the following error: clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/programmer/Desktop/cocos2d-swift-3.2/external/Chipmunk/src/cpPinJoint.c'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1

Comment: Does the same with 3.3

Comment: Honestly, don't know how anyone can use this framework.  I've run into similar probs w/cocos in the past -- it's always, always buggy, yet its been reported 25% of the games in the appstore use, mind blown. What a nightmare.

Comment: This particular problem affects any cocos2d version because Apple fundamentally changed the xml parser. This can't really be held against cocos2d. The issue has since been fixed for iOS. Bugs are to be expected in any game engine, honestly I'm glad I don't have to wait for Apple or Unity (for instance) to provide fixes instead.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D which version should I download then? I downloaded 3.2, 3.2.1 and 3.3 -- please advise?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I also just downloaded GIT Master and I get the same error (see comment above). So please validate your comment with a a copy I can actually compile without issue.

Comment: The xml parsing issue was marked fixed (at least for iOS): https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-swift/issues/964

You may need to sync with the develop branch.